# Checkbox is not working properly with ng-repeat, AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I want to make multiselect checkbox using ng-repeat. It is working fine if I don't have pre-selected checkbox. But when I have preselected checkbox then its behaviour is totally unusual.

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    <input ng-model="selectedAccounts[account.id]"              
    ng-checked="{{account.lastchecked}}" type="checkbox">       
</div>
```

In Controller I got selected id as:

```
$scope.selectedAccounts = [];
angular.forEach($scope.selectedAccounts, function(value, key) {
    if(value == true) {
        selectedIds.push(key);
    }
});
```

The problem here is that I have to initialise selectedAccounts with initial array. If I don't do this then it gives me undefined. When I have 'lastchecked' true for some accounts then it shows pre-checked values according to lastchecked but when I try to retreive $scope.selectedAccounts it give me empty array. But when I manually check/uncheck each option then $scope.selectedAccounts give me correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do it :

```
$scope.context = {accounts : :[]};// init is important to place the variable in that scope on not in a child
<div ng-repeat="account in context.accounts">
    <input ng-model="account.lastchecked" ng-checked="account.lastchecked"              
       ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" type="checkbox">       
</div>
```

Ng-true-value and ng-false-value ensure that the value will be the boolean true/false instead of strings.

After to get the selectedAccount you just search.filter account with `lastchecked==true`

The indermediary object context is to avoid scope issues, scope inheritance fails on simple fields. This is a limit of javascript. In angularJS this is called DOT notation.

Comment: $scope.context = {accounts : :[]};
Here accounts is $scope.accounts right ?

Comment: yes but it's on purpose, as said in my last sentece, this avoid scope problem, your code might not working if you use some directive between the controller declaration and the ng-repeat. There are recurrent case here because of `ngIf`.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.selectedAccounts = {"3":true};
  $scope.accounts = [{id:1, name:"account1", checked: true}, {id:2, name:"account2"}, {id:3, name:"account3"}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    <input ng-model="selectedAccounts[account.id]"              
    ng-checked="selectedAccounts[account.id]" type="checkbox">{{account.name}}       
  </div>
  <div>{{selectedAccounts}}</div>
</div>
```